# How to use query function LIKE and CONCAT in the same time

Tags: php, regex, symfony, query-builder, doctrine-query

User will send a message for example

`user1 = "Show football score today plz"
 user2 = "Show basketball score yesterday lol"`

the key is  "**score**"

I want to query that word form all sentence by use this two function

`function like()` and `function concat()` in the same time

I want that code something like this

`LIKE CONCAT('%', message, '%')
LIKE CONCAT('Show football ', score,' today plz')`

and this is my code

```
class MatchingMessageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByReceiveMessage($message)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->where(parent::expr()->like('o.message', ':message'))
            ->setParameter('message', '%' . $message . '%')
            ->orderBy('o.message', 'ASC')
        ;

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking. Did you tried that code? In current form it sounds more like a question for the codereview.stackexchange com.

Comment: @RuslanBes Oh sorry about that I'll explain in a minutes

Comment: what do you want to concat?